# details tag in XHTML

Tags: xml, xhtml

Im wondering if anyone have a solution on how to use:

```
<details>
   <summary> </summary>
   <p> bla bla </p>
</details>
```

in xhtml transitional. Or is it even possible? Ive read on w3schools that it with different syntax but doesnt explain how.

Comment: https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-details-element.html

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use XHTML Transitional? The only reason I can think of is that you want the validator to not gag on <font>, <center> etc. In such a mindset, there's no place for <details>.

Comment: By the way, I've read the W3Schools page, but I'm not sure what you mean with it showing "a different syntax". Different from what? Oh, and it says that <details> is available in Firefox 49, but it actually is available in FF 47 and 48 if you set the about:config entry _dom.details_element.enabled_ to true.

Comment: Objectively, the answer to the question is "You can just use it, if you have a new enough browser", but I'm not sure that's what you're asking.

Comment: Well maybe syntax whas not the right word. It says that it possible to use in XHTML. Im doing an assignment in school and we are processing losts of data from xml to xhtml with xslt and it felt easy to use this method to make it less bloated. This does work however it doesnt validate.

Comment: @Dragan In that case, refer to my first comment, why do you need XHTML Transitional. It works the same way no matter what DOCTYPE you have, and it validates under the XHTML5 one.

Comment: Hehe i dont have to i have just been using it in the past and was rolling with it. What XHTML DOCTYPE do u suggest me using? I used strict once but that was just annoying.

Comment: @Dragan Just the XHTML5 one, `<!DOCTYPE html>`. But tell me, in what way is the strict one annoying? I'm afraid the XHTML5 one won't be much better, in that it makes the validator complain about the same elements.

Comment: Hmm ok. I dont remember exactly what was annoying but i remember when going for transitional most of the "wrongs" dissapared. But im going to try make something like this with js instead. Thanks for ur help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work the comments into an answer...

First of all, the <details> element doesn't work in all browsers yet. Not at all in IE; it has some restrictions in Safari; and in Firefox and Chrome only the very latest versions are OK. See [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=details).

Then the doctype declaration. If you really are using XHTML (that is, with a .xhtml file extension, or using a proper XHTML MIME type) it doesn't really matter to the browsers which DOCTYPE you have. XHTML files are always rendered in standards mode, and elements that are supported are always supported, no matter if they're mentioned in the DTD or not.
(For example, a browser that supports <font> always supports this, whether you have a proper doctype or not. Having, say, a XHTML 1.0 Strict doctype doesn't prevent <font> from working.)

So the only reason why you would choose a certain doctype is if you want your document to validate against it. In that case, only the XHTML5 one `<!DOCTYPE html>` is applicable, since that's the only one that has <details>.
Choosing this one does mean it won't validate stuff like <font> though.
You will have to decide what you want.